# Undef a define at user options level

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, preprocessor-directive

Is there any way I can undef a preprocessor macro via vcxproj.user or .suo file in Visual Studio?

Already scanned on Microsoft Visual Studio interface, searched on Internet, asked on IRC channels, etc. but did not reach a definitive answer.

I will explain the scenario:
There is a `#define` that produces a LOT of text to the Debug Output Window which is useful for another colleague. As I do not need that output and it even prevents me from see my own output debug messages, it would be nice to have VS to output only my text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this in the vcxproj.user file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <UndefinePreprocessorDefinitions>DEFINE_TO_UNDEFINE;%(UndefinePreprocessorDefinitions)</UndefinePreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer pointed me in the right direction, which I will explain in more detail after.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @Rami A., I had the following code:

```
ifdef _DEBUG
#define LOG_EVENT(FormatString, ...) \
    {\
        CTime Now = CTime::GetCurrentTime();\
        int nTime = MindUtilsLib::GetCurrentTimeMsec();\
        CString sMessage;\
        sMessage.Format(CString(_T("EVENT(%05d): ")) + CString(FormatString) + CString(_T("\n")), nTime, __VA_ARGS__);\
        ::OutputDebugString(sMessage);\
    }
#else
#define LOG_EVENT(FormatString, ...)
#endif // _DEBUG
```

and I changed the first line to

```
#if defined(_DEBUG) && !defined(DISABLE_EVENTS_LOGGING)
```

then I made the `.vcxproj.user` file to be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>DISABLE_EVENTS_LOGGING;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

The reason I chose to made based on a user-specific define instead of an undefine is for not annoying anyone else into not having the behavior they already had before; otherwise they would need to change their defines to have it.